# How to use another classes' functions in Java

Tags: java, swing, class

First time using the stackoverflow. So, please don't be too harsh :)

I have a little Java project. We are learning how to built GUI with swing. I am stuck with methodology.

I have a `JFrame` for GUI and I am creating 4 `JPanels` for:

Menu (Menu Class)
Buttons (Buttons Class)
ActionArea (ActionArea Class)
Statusbar (StatusBar Class)

I have been asked to have **same** options in the Menu and Buttons. i.e. New File or Open File options will be available in the Menu and Buttons sections.

I don't want to duplicate the code and copy into Menu Class and Buttons Class. I believe there is a way to use only one function from both classes.

Could somebody help me to achieve this?

Here is main code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    private Menu menu;
    private Buttons buttons;
    private ActionArea actionArea;
    private StatusBar statusBar;

    public GUI() {
        super("New GUI");

        this.setSize(800, 600);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setLayout (new BorderLayout());

        this.menu = new Menu();
                this.buttons = new Buttons();
        this.actionArea = new ActionArea();
        this.statusBar = new StatusBar();

        this.setJMenuBar(this.menu);

        add(this.toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(this.actionArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(this.statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

lets say the function name is `newFile();`

I don't want to write this function one for menu class and one for buttons class.

Thanks in advance to all

EDIT:

`this.menu = new Menu();` creates `menuitems` with required `actions` in `Menu class`

`this.buttons = new Buttons();` creates `jbuttons` with required `actions` in `Buttons class`

`actions` are exactly same. Code is doubled. This is the problem.

Comment: Take a look at [How to use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Comment: Also, read about the Command Design pattern:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Comment: I already used `Actions` for each `menuitem` and `jbuttons`. the problem is menuitems and jbuttons belong to different classes. Now, I have 2 sets of same Actions. One set is in `menu class` for `menuitems` and another (same) set is in `buttons class` for `jbuttons`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your `Button` class to take the object of `Menu` class as parameter in its constructor. Now, with this object, you can get access to the `Action` classes of your `Menu` class, and then, you can use them for your button.

If you still can't understand, please provide the code of your `Button` and `Menu` classes.

Comment: I think that's the right approach. Thanks for the advice. Let me try.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Swing [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html).  See [How to use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for details on using them in buttons and menu items.

Comment: I already used Actions for each `menuitem` and `jbuttons`. the problem is `menuitems` and `jbuttons` belong to different classes. Now, I have 2 sets of same Actions. One set is in menu class for `menuitems` and another (same) set is in buttons class for `jbuttons`. These classes are **not** part of GUI class.

Comment: So ..fix that first.  Why are you telling me?

Comment: Because that it is not something fixable. It has to be like that. Each part of GUI has to be created in its own Class. This is the design requirement. Also, I didn't just tell you. I wrote the same thing to the other commenters. Seems like, everybody has got the same thought that all my code is in one file, under one class. Just wanted to clarify that to get correct answer.

Comment: *"Seems like, everybody has got the same thought that all my code is in one file, under one class."*  At no point did I presume that.  OTOH it makes a lot of sense to make all the actions in one single class.

Comment: _" it makes a lot of sense to make all the actions in one single class"_ This is what I am trying to do. However, Although, Menuitems and buttons have to be in different classes, they must use same actions. I could not figured out this part yet.

Comment: Have the one class with the actions provide a `getActions()` method.  Or if you want to make them more specific `getFileActions()`, `getEditActions()`...  Note that this Java 101, whereas making GUIs is Java 201 (or something significantly higher).  You really should have these types of problems sorted before attempting to make GUIs.

Comment: I have created a new separate class with `extends AbstractAction`. I think now all I need is to figure out how to understand which component was initiated/pressed. Because, menuitems have text values are set where buttons only have icons. I need to find a way to recognize buttons.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Action class which is an extension of ActionListener....there are several properties you can set in objects of these class...you can check out the line:
[Tutorial for Using Action classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

and for API: [Action classes API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html)

it may help you..

Comment: I already used Actions for each `menuitem` and `jbuttons`. the problem is `menuitems` and `jbuttons` belong to different classes. Now, I have 2 sets of same Actions. One set is in menu class for `menuitems` and another (same) set is in buttons class for `jbuttons`. These classes are **not** part of GUI class.